# Read DICOM in C++ and convert to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, dicom, mat, dcmtk

I would like to read DICOM images in C++ and manipulate them using opencv.

I managed to read a dicom image using DCMTK however, I am unsure how to convert it to an opencv Mat.

The following is what I have so far:

```
DicomImage DCM_image("test.dcm");
cv::Mat image(int(DCM_image.getWidth()), int(DCM_image.getHeight()), CV_8U, (uchar*)DCM_image.getOutputData(8));
```

which results in the following:

[image]

In a DICOM viewer, it looks as follows:

[image]

After normalising, the grayed image appears as follows:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I can see now is the difference of pixel value ranges (depths).

AFAIK, DICOM can have a rather big depth (16 bit), and you are trying to fit in into `CV_8U`, which is only 8 bit. You can get `DicomImage` instance's depth using [DicomImage::getDepth()](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/classDicomImage.html#3e2fbb233db62bd59a25e4c0c2fc673c), and then create a `cv::Mat` with appropriate depth to hold your image data.

You may also need to normalize the data to maximally utilize you available range, so that the display with `cv::imshow()` would look as expected.

So:

- Do `DicomImage::getDepth()` on your DCM_image
- Create a `cv::Mat` with sufficient depth to hold your data
- Scale, if necessary

Comment: I'll give it a go. Also, normalising should be done before or after transfering data to opencv? If before, is this to be done with the getOutputData as well? Thanks

Comment: I think that if you select the depth appropriately, there is not any difference. Also, from my experience some DICOM viewers have  unusual normalization, that causes data to go out of range (the structure on your screenshot looks completely white, like it is overexposed). So perhaps you would like to normalize your data differently.

Comment: I am creating the cv::mat as follows:
  
`cv::Mat test(int(DCM_image.getHeight()), int(DCM_image.getWidth()), CV_MAKETYPE(DCM_image.getDepth(), 1), (long*)DCM_image.getOutputData()); `
  
However the output is still not any good. Any idea why?

Comment: I checked the bit depth, it's 17 (which is a strange number in my opinion). This time the output is plain wrong, not even the structure is there

Comment: Then I would avoid using CV_MAKETYPE, and stick to int of float as Mat's type. But I am not sure how the data is laid out inside DCM_image. I think you'd better refer to DCMTK manual to find out stride, padding, etc, instead of trying to guess.

Comment: I managed to obtain a much better image by normalising he above, grayed out image (in the question). However, the whites are still not there...

Comment: That means you normalize it in a different way. You can find min and max of the image data, subtract min and multiply by normalized_max/(max-min) where normalized_max is the maximal value that you want to have.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I am not that familiar with DICOM. What do the stride, padding etc mean and how do they affect the image?

Comment: They are related to image representation in general, and not to DICOM format. Basically stride is size of one image row in bytes, and padding is special alignment of pixel values in memory to increase performance.

In order to be sure what is going on I would suggest you copy the data from DICOM structure to cv::Mat in a loop, pixel by pixel and scale it as you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108095/discussion-between-user3126802-and-user3896254).

Comment: problem solved by using the width centre and width to normalise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3126802 could you please post a full working example? Maybe editing this answer or adding a new one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before calling DicomImage::getOutputData() on a monochrome DICOM image, you should make sure that you've selected an appropriate VOI transformation (e.g. Window Center & Width). This could be done by DicomImage::setMinMaxWindow(), DicomImage::setWindow() etc. See documentation of the [DicomImage](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html) class.

Please note, however, that DicomImage::getOutputData() always returns rendered pixel data, i.e. not the original Pixel Data that is stored in the DICOM dataset.

Answer (score -1):

U need to read the data type in DICOM image encoding an convert that to opencv type Mat. The opencv docs provides the entire information on their Mat header.

Comment: In your CV mat header, the width and height needs to be swapped. How different is the result from the Original.

Comment: You are correct. I'm more concerned about the intensities though. I' ll post an image to show you how it appears on a DICOM reader.